# Converting exported private key from Microsoft SQL Server to PEM and back to PVK

Tags: security, sql-server

I have need to backup the cert and private key for SQL TDE and store that on a KeySecure key management system.

I can do the backup and get the files, and have no issue with converting the certificate from MS format to something usable on the KeySecure, and converting it back out to something that SQL Server likes.

The issue is with the private key in MS proprietary .pvk file.  I can use openssl to convert it to PEM, which I can then import into the KeySecure.  However that PEM file doesn't seem to be convertible back to the same binary .pvk.  File compares are vastly different.

I've tried putting the cert and key into a pfx file and using PVKConverter from Microsoft, as well as a utility I found called pvk.exe.

Reversing the openssl command to output a pvk from pem also fails.

Anyone know a way to get this done?

Comment: I found the utility pvk2pfx in the MS SDK.  So I took the key and cert from MS SQL cert backup and created a pfx with that.  The other utility PVKConverter takes a pfx and produces a key and cert in MS format.  Sounds like just what is needed.  Unfortunately giving the output of the pfx creation to the converter, while it does create a cert and key file, the key file does not match the original input key that came from SQL Server.  <heavy sigh>.

Comment: OK finally found the answer.  Use openssl going from pem to pvk.  You must also use the -pvk-strong parameter which is only available if you also have the fips module installed in openssl.